# React Native: Issue with TextInput - Value Not Updating on State Change

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing a challenge in my React Native project related to the TextInput component. Despite having a state to track the input value, the TextInput value doesn't seem to update when typing. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (text) => {
    setInputValue(text);
    console.log('Input value:', inputValue); // Always logs the previous value
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={inputValue}
        placeholder="Type something..."
        onChangeText={handleChange}
      />
      <Text>Current Value: {inputValue}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Even though the handleChange function correctly updates the state with the new value, the console.log statement logs the previous value. This behavior causes the Text component to display the previous value as well.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue with the TextInput value not updating in sync with the state? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here, it's the way react states update works!
See the first caveat point in the [useState docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats).

[This example](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value) from the docs clarifies the behavior you've
seen.

Answer (score 0):

React / React Native does not immediately updates the state below is the documentation refference, however there are a few ways you can get the updated values.

```
const handleChange = (text) => {
  setInputValue(text);
  console.log('Input value:', text); // It will console updated 
};
```

Below is another way, but it is not recommended, as it will cause performance issues:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Input value:', inputValue);
  }, [inputValue]);
```

[Documentation Ref:](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats)

[image: React use state]